# Load a folder from LocalSystem to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a folder in my LocalSystem. It contains 1000 files, and I would move or copy him from my LocalSystem to HDFS

I tried by these two commands:

`hadoop fs copyFromLocal C:/Users/user/Downloads/ProjectSpark/ling-spam /tmp`

And I also tried this command:

`hdfs dfs -put /C:/Users/user/Downloads/ProjectSpark/ling-spam 
/tmp/ling-spam`

It displays an error message which says that my directory not found and yet I'm sure that correct.
I found a function getmerge() to move a folder from HDFS to LocalSystem, but I did not find the inverse.

Please, can you help me?

Comment: The command you used looks correct... though, it is `-copyFromLocal`

Comment: i added the (-) but also the same error:  copyFromLocal: `/Users/user/Downloads/ProjectSpark/ling-spam': No such file or directory

Comment: `/tmp` should exist if you've setup HDFS correctly. And I assume that directory you are trying to copy does exist as well. Can you find your `hdfs-site.xml` file and add it to the question?

Comment: i can't find him !

Comment: in fact my VirtualBox on Windows, and i work by HDP2.3.2 with the console secure shell.

Answer (score 0):

> my VirtualBox on Windows, and i work by HDP2.3.2 with the console secure shell

You can't copy files from your Windows machine to HDFS. You have to first SCP the files into the VM (I recommend WinSCP or Filezilla) and only then can you use `hadoop fs` to put files onto HDFS.

The error was correct in that `C:/Users/user/Downloads` does not exist on the HDP sandbox because it's a Linux machine.

As noted, you can also try and use the Ambari HDFS file viewer, but I still standby by note that SCP is the official way because not all Hadoop systems have Ambari (or at least the HDFS file view for Ambari)

Comment: how i cant added my directory C:/Users/user/Downloads on HDP sandbox ?

Comment: You can't. It's running Linux. Not Windows

Comment: Ok, i added my folder by Ambari.

Comment: Sure, Ambari would work, but SCP is the official way to do it, as noted in my answer. If your problem has been resolved by this post, you may accept it with the checkmark next to it

Comment: Hello! thank you for your answer, but i can't resolve the problem by SCP :/ i added my folder by Ambari to worked my project quickly, i must return it this Saturday -:)

Answer (score 0):

I would take the Mutual Information for classification of the word spam or ham. I have this operation: MI(Word)= ∑ Probabi(Occ,Class) * Log2 * (Probabi(Occuren,Class)/Probabi(Occurren) * Probabi(Class)).
I understand the function, I must compute 4 operation (true,ham), (false,ham), (true,spam) and (false,spam).
I do not understand who i do write exactly, in fact, I computed the number of the file in which in occur.
But I do not who exactly I must write in my function.
Thank you very much!

This isthe corps of my function:
def computeMutualInformationFactor(
    probaWC:RDD[(String, Double)],// probability of occurrence of the word in a given class.
    probaW:RDD[(String, Double)],// probability of occurrence of the word in whether class
    probaC: Double, //probability an email appears in class (spam or ham)
    probaDefault: Double // default value when a probability is missing
  ):RDD[(String, Double)] = {